# Power Bi formula Value.Is([Column], type date) not working

Tags: powerbi-desktop

I'am working on this turtorial from PluralSight and have a problem converting a column with date & decimals to sperate columns.
According the turorial the formula if Value.Is([Value], type date) = true then [Value] else null
to create a custom column with name date

Anyone that knows a solution?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have adapted the forumula for now
= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Date", each **if Text.Contains([Value], "/") then** Date.From([Value],"en-US") else null)

Answer (score 0):

[image]Create A New Custom Colum with ‘= try Date.FromText([Value]) otherwise null’ as long as your Options > CURRENT FILE > ‘Regional Settings is set on English (United States). Your query will add a query line with “= Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type1", "Date", each try Date.FromText([Value]) otherwise null)”  [(#"Changed Type1" being the previous query line]

Note: I previously suggested “if Value.Is(Date.FromText([Value], [Format="MM/dd/yyyy", Culture="en-US"]), Date.Type) then [Value] else null” which does not work on several levels, i.e. the Culture argument and the if Value.Is . After testing your data, I learned that “try” […] “otherwise” (as opposed to if then else) seems to be the only “error handling” possible for this type of purpose. One for my PowerQuery m Language skills library from now on…
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ER10p.png)